# Asus VG249Q monitor - HDMI not working when DisplayPort connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I have Asus VG249Q (TUF Gaming) monitor and I used USB-C -> DisplayPort cable to connect the laptop with the monitor (works fine).

If I keep this cable connected, then my HDMI connection is not working (I have PlayStation 4 on HDMI).

As soon as I disconnect the DisplayPort cable, the HDMI starts working (no restart, no unplugging the HDMI, nothing, it just works).

If I plug the DisplayPort cable again, then HDMI will lose connection.
Monitor says "HDMI no connection".

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "Is there a way to fix this?" - Have you tried to switch the inputs on the displayed?  There should be an button to allow you to switch from DisplayPort to HDMI.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I did try to switch the input from DisplayPort to HDMI, but still it's not working, only if I unplug the DisplayPort then it works.